# Laravel mix raw queries with ORM in blade

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

I have a raw query in my controller that is used to sort a parent by one of its children:

```
$tags = DB::select(DB::raw(
        "
         SELECT *
         FROM
         (
         SELECT path, url, position, protocol, domain, ut.occurrences, ut.id
         FROM unknown_tags ut
         INNER JOIN paths p
         ON ut.id = p.tag_id
         )t1
         WHERE t1.position = '$pathNum'
         ORDER BY t1.path asc
         "
    ),array('pos' => $pathNum ));
    return view('index', compact('tags'));
```

This works fine; I can use echo to see that the results are what I expect. The problem is when I call my view. I would like to to make a call to the parents children via the ORM:

```
@foreach($tag->Paths as $path)
        <td class="Column">{{$path->path}}</td>
```

This throws an error telling me that $Paths does not exist. How can I set up my raw query so I can still use ORM to loop through the children in blade? I am aware that I could change my blade to fix this problem, but the blade page I am calling is multi-use and I would really rather not change it.

Comment: You could utilize the ORM to build your query. That's it.

Comment: Could you explain how I could do that? I am trying to order my parent table based on one of its children. The child specified depends on the variable $pathPos.